# Trouble adding object into constructor

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist, constructor

For a school project we are supposed to create a simple program that takes some input from the user about Dogs (name, breed, age and weight) and puts them into an ArrayList. Everything seems to be working, but to test the program I want to add some dogs in my method setUp() so that you can test the functions without having to add a new dog every time, which is where i'm lost! If I write the constuctor (Dog Dog = new Dog("Alex", "Pug", 10, 10.0) in setUp(), I get the error message:

`The value of the local variable Dog is not used`.

I've tried to put the constructor in case "1" as well, then I don't get any errors but the dog is not added to the arraylist, while I can add new dogs inside the program. I'm really clueless what to do next. The dog needs to be added into the Dog-constructor for the assignment (parts of the code is cropped to be relevant, don't worry about imports or main).

```
class DogReg {
private ArrayList<Dog> allDogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

private void setUp() {
    System.out.print("Hi! Welcome to the Dog register! \n" + "Choose an option between 1-5\n");
    System.out.println("1. Register your dog");
    System.out.println("2. Increase age");
    System.out.println("3. List");
    System.out.println("4. Delete");
    System.out.println("5. Exit");
}

private void runCommandLoop() {

    // Initierar en while-loop som körs under tiden att willRun == true
    boolean willRun = true;
    while (willRun == true) {

        System.out.print("> ");

        // Skapar en variabel som konverterar input-sträng till lowerCase
        String command = keyboard.next();
        switch (command) {

        case "1":
            // Konstruerar en ny hund in i ArrayList
            Dog Dog = new Dog();
            // Sparar all input till ArrayList
            System.out.print("\nThe name of the dog: ");
            Dog.setName(keyboard.next());
            System.out.print("The breed of the dog: ");
            Dog.setBreed(keyboard.next());
            System.out.print("The age of the dog: ");
            int age = keyboard.nextInt();
            Dog.setAge(age);
            System.out.print("The weight of the dog: ");
            double weight = keyboard.nextDouble();
            Dog.setWeight(weight);
            allDogs.add(Dog);
            break;
```

class Dog {

```
private String name;
private String breed;
private int age;
private double weight;

public Dog (String name, String breed, int age, double weight){
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getBreed() {
    return breed;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setBreed(String breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

I can add a dog in setUp() if I'm  using this code instead, but we're not supposed to use that:

```
Dog Dog = new Dog();
Dog.setName("Bosse");
Dog.setBreed("Mops");
int age = 10;
Dog.setAge(age);
double weight = 10;
Dog.setWeight(weight);
allDogs.add(Dog);
```

Hope it's clear enough, I apologize for grammar and/or spelling, English is not my first language.

Comment: I didn't thoroughly read your code but one thing: `Dog Dog = new Dog();` - avoid such naming at all cost, it will eventually confuse you and introduce bugs. Thus try to stick to the Java naming conventions which state that variable names should start with a lower case letter, i.e. `Dog dog = new Dog();`. - Think about what happens at this line: `Dog.setName(keyboard.next());` - what's `Dog` here? Is it the class or the variable you're referring to? The compiler just can't know and you probably won't either when reading your code again sometime later.

Comment: You should respect the [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): `Dog dog = new Dog();`

Comment: If you ask about an error cause by some code, post the exact and complete error message, and post the code causing the error. Not some other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your Dog variable something different. You're naming your variable the same thing as the name of the object and it's confusing the compiler. Try this, for example:

```
Dog newDog = new Dog();
newDog.setName("Bosse");
newDog.setBreed("Mops");
int age = 10;
newDog.setAge(age);
double weight = 10;
newDog.setWeight(weight);
allDogs.add(newDog);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it did help!

Comment: @zkulltrail make sure you upvote answers you find helpful and if my answer solved your problem, you can click the checkmark to accept it. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Follow up question. I want an constructor that is empty for my Case "1" (where I add more dogs) but it feels cheap just to leave it completely blank, is there another way to do it?

Edit: I'm talking about: 
public DogArr (){
 }

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using an empty constructor but you could consider gathering all of the data from the user into variables and putting those into your dog constructor.